# Showing that $x = \sec\theta + \tan\theta$ and $y = 2\sec\theta$ satisfy $x^{2}-xy+1=0$ without substitution?

Tags: trigonometry

> Show that $x = \sec\theta + \tan\theta$ and $y = 2\sec\theta$ satisfy $x^{2}-xy+1=0$

I would sub, but are there alternative methods to consider?

Comment: Substitution would be the best method as if you want to make $y$ in terms of $x$, you should naturally consider the sign of $x,y$ (you cannot say $\sec\theta=\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}$ because $\sec\theta$ may be negative), so you need to split so many subcase, but that's too stupid.

Comment: Don't know why people have voted to close this question, it is actually a very good deep question for someone not accepting mediocre paths.

Comment: A challenging way to consider is to go meta , instead of just subbing these specific cases trying more general form of function that this values are a specific case of .

Comment: **Hint** $x^2-xy+1= \left({x-\frac{y}{2}}\right)^2-\frac{y^2}{4}+1$ 

Let : $u =x-\frac{y}{2}  $ and v = y

 We obtain the general Pell’s equation
$u^2-\frac{1}{4}v^2=-1$ and look this Book : https://www.amazon.fr/Quadratic-Diophantine-Equations-Titu-Andreescu/dp/1493938800

Comment: Recall that $\sec \theta - \tan \theta$ is reciprocal of $\sec \theta + \tan \theta$. Hence $y = x + \dfrac{1}{x}$

Comment: What is $$y-x=?$$  then $$x(y-x)=?$$

Comment: You can postpone substitution but you can not avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the question wants us to prove
$$x\left(y-x\right)=1$$
and we also know the standard result,
$$\sec^{2}\theta=1+\tan^{2}\theta$$
$$\sec^{2}\theta-\tan^{2}\theta=1$$
$$\left(\sec\theta+\tan\theta\right)\left(\sec\theta-\tan\theta\right)=1$$
Now the LHS is exactly $x\left(y-x\right)$.
You know the line of thought used here, and thus the proof is complete.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=\secθ+\tanθ$$
Squaring both sides
$$x^2=(\secθ+\tanθ)^2$$
$$=\sec^2θ+\tan^2θ+2\secθ\tanθ$$

Now we have to use the identity $$\sec^2θ-1=\tan^2θ$$
So $$x^2= 2\sec^2θ-1+2\secθ\tanθ$$
Or
$$x^2=2\secθ(\secθ+\tanθ) -1$$
Or
$$x^2=yx -1$$
As $y=2\secθ$

Hence $$x^2-xy+1=0$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. When using MathJax write the trigonometric functions (and other common functions) as `\tan`, `\sec`, etc. to get a better formatting. Compare "$sec\theta tan\theta$" with "$\sec\theta\tan\theta$"

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^{2}-xy+1=0 \iff xy = x^2+1 \iff y=\frac{x^2+1}{x} = x+\frac{1}{x}$, the curve has infinitely many parametrizations, for example

$$x=t, y=t+\frac{1}{t}$$

or

$$x=\tan(t), y=\tan(t)+\frac{1}{\tan(t)}$$

Whatever you choose for $x$, there will be a corresponding function for $y$, so you will have to do a substitution at some point to check that the specific parametrization you were given works.